# Resize image doesn't work with PHP-GD

Tags: php, php-gd

Following my code:

```
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("dir");
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("dir"); 
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
imagecopyresampled($im, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 300, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($src, 'img.jpg');
```

It saves the image, but with the same size of originary image and not 300x300. How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used wrong image handler with `imagejpeg` function. Use:

```
imagejpeg($im, 'img.jpg');
```